# Confirming wave function for particle on a sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The Hamiltonian operator for a particle with mass *m* on a sphere with radius $r_0$ can be written as:
$\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2mr_0^2}\hat{\Lambda}^2$

where

$\hat{\Lambda}^2=\frac{1}{sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial \varphi^2}+\frac{1}{sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$

The solutions for $\psi_{lm_l}(\theta\varphi)$ are $Y_{lm_l}(\theta\varphi)$.

Confirm that $Y_{11}(\theta\varphi)=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}sin\theta e^{i\varphi}$ is a solution and find the energy $E_{11}$.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is you need to show that

$$
\hat{H}\psi_{11}(\theta,\phi) = E_{11}\psi_{11}(\theta,\phi)
$$

So it boils down to calculate the effect of $\hat{\Lambda}$ on $\psi_{11}$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\Lambda}^2\psi_{11}(\theta,\phi) &=& \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2 \psi_{11}}{\partial\phi^2} + \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial\psi_{11}}{\partial\theta}\right) \\
&=& (\cdots) \\
&=& \left(\frac{3}{2\pi}\right)\sin\theta e^{i\phi} = -2\psi_{11}(\theta,\phi)
\end{eqnarray}

That is

$$
\hat{H}\psi_{11} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2mr_0^2}\hat{\Lambda}^2\psi_{11} = \frac{2\hbar^2}{2mr_0^2}\psi_{11} = E_{11}\psi_{11}
$$

that is, $\psi_{11}$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ with eigenvalue

$$
E_{11} = \frac{\hbar^2}{mr_0^2}
$$

Comment: what are the intermediate steps on calculatong the effects on $\hat{\Lambda}$ on $\psi_{11}$

Comment: @ChemGuy I am sorry, but that is the part of the homework you will have to complete yourself